# Write to OUTFILE with Procedure and Event - MySQL

Tags: mysql, procedure, into-outfile

Could someone help me with what is wrong with the below please?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`user1`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Local_sp_ExtractPOI`()
BEGIN

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SET @OutputPath := 'C:/stuff/folder/nextfolder/files/POIExtract/';
SET @filename := date_format(now(), '%d%m%y_%H%m%s.txt');
SET @fullOutputPath := CONCAT(@OutputPath, @filename);

set @q1 := concat("SELECT group_concat(`NHS` separator '') INTO OUTFILE ",@fullOutputPath,
" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\'
FROM person WHERE `active` = -1 AND `NHS` IS NOT NULL AND `NHS` REGEXP [0123456789]{10} 
ORDER BY 1");

prepare s1 from @q1;
execute s1; deallocate prepare s1;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I know i can write to the path because this works:

```
SELECT oid INTO OUTFILE "C:/stuff/folder/nextfolder/files/POIExtract/varmydata.txt"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM person limit 1;
```

However, when i wrap in a procedure and use the variables and `concat()`, it doesn't create the outfile.

I have tried multiple ways of formatting the filepath but still no dice.  When i try to call it i get Error Code: 1064.  You have an error in your SQL syntax...

Is it something around using `REGEXP` this way that i am not understanding?

I intend to call it using a scheduled event.

TYIA,

Mike

Comment: If you think its the REGEX thats causing the issue, remove it and see if the proceedure then runs. If you still get the error its not the REGEX. _Simple testing_

Comment: These errors _Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax..._ normally give you a bigger clue as to where the error is. **Please always show the complete error message** Not just a summary

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3813b20dadf6906cb2932a63ac75dfe6 The filename is not enclosed with `'`. The same about regex pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Not sure why the down votes....you can't ask a question on this website without some snarky comment. I thought it might have changed in the 3 or somewhat years since needing it but obviously not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akina was right.  Modified to this:

`` set @q1 := concat("SELECT group_concat(`NHS` separator '') INTO OUTFILE ", " '", @fullOutputPath, "' ", " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\' FROM p_person WHERE `active` = -1 AND `NHS` IS NOT NULL AND `NHS` REGEXP", " '[0123456789]{10}' ", "ORDER BY 1"); ``